# why all documents are imported in check out

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, import, check-out

I've an issue with an import of documents in client object model.
My import run correctly an imported my documents not check out and after 12h, every documents arrive check out.

I changed nothing in the site and NORMALLY nobody makes one.
What could be change to import document in check out?

I suppose the code is correct because it worked till a certain time and it still work on an other site collection

Comment: Does the library have "Require Checkout to Edit" turned on?

Comment: no is selected and it's in all my document library

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Someone changed a column of my content type in required and when you savebinary the document, it doesn't have the required value so it's in check out